# How does pyright retain argument type information with `partial`?

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance, pyright

Take this simple example

```py
from functools import partial

def foo(a: str, b: int, c: float, d:str) -> bool:
    print(a, b, c, d)
    return True

bar = partial(foo, 'a', 1, 2.0)
bar()  # error
```

Pyright can correctly identify that `bar` needs another argument named `d` of type `str`, but how? I looked at both the actual definition of partial (in python 3.8 - 3.10) and the typeshed types. The actual definition has no types of course, but this is what my typeshed partial definition looks like

```py
class partial(Generic[_T]):
    @property
    def func(self) -> Callable[..., _T]: ...
    @property
    def args(self) -> tuple[Any, ...]: ...
    @property
    def keywords(self) -> dict[str, Any]: ...
    def __new__(cls, __func: Callable[..., _T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Self: ...
    def __call__(__self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _T: ...
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
        def __class_getitem__(cls, item: Any) -> GenericAlias: ...
```

Nothing about that definition should be preserving the types because it just uses `Any` and `...` in place of args. You can even copy it out, rename it to `mypartial`, try to use it and observe that you don't get the same type safety. My understanding is that you might be able to preserve the type information with `ParamSpec` but that isn't being used here and my version of Python can't access it anyway.

Am I missing something or does Pyright just hard code knowledge about what certain things should be, regardless of the types?

Comment: `functools.partial` is special-cased in pyright, probably [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/506345aa77cde058f9245e13b92381d4b21de7db/packages/pyright-internal/src/analyzer/constructorTransform.ts#L216). This, along with some other standard library constructs such as `@property...@<property>.setter` and `enum.Enum` are not generally describable using standard type annotations, and so must be special-cased by type-checkers on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: "*[...] my version of Python can't access it anyway*": What version is it? For 3.5 and higher you should be able to use the type annotation syntax, which is the minimal condition to use any kind of type hints, since new features are backported via [`typing_extensions`](https://github.com/python/typing_extensions).

Comment: Function annotations were introduced in Python 3.0. The `typing` module, which introduced the systematic use of function annotations specifically for *type hinting*, appeared in Python 3.5. (Variable annotations were added in Python 3.6 in support of type hinting.)